# React: Returned letters instead of whole value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple list where I have radio inputs for each element. They behave separately meaning that each selection changes the state of that specific element.

Now when I'm trying to set a default value `option2` for

```
  const [Selected, setSelected] = useState("option2");
```

In the `console.log(Selected)`, instead of returning `option2`, I have the following

```
{0: "o", 1: "p", 2: "t", 3: "option3", 4: "o"…}
0: "o"
1: "p"
2: "t"
3: "option3"
4: "o"
5: "n"
6: "2"
```

**How can I manage to return a proper value such as `option1` so I can have a default state ?**

https://codesandbox.io/s/little-snowflake-j26b7?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default () => {
  const initialList = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "John"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Eric"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Jonathan"
    }
  ];

  const handleChangeSelected = (e, id) => {
    setSelected({
      ...Selected,
      [id]: e.target.value
    });
  };
  const [list, setList] = useState(initialList);
  const [Selected, setSelected] = useState("option2");
  console.log(Selected);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <div>
          {list.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <div>
                <div className="users">{item.name}</div>
                <p />{" "}
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={item.id}
                  name={item.id}
                  value="option1"
                  checked={Selected[item.id] === "option1"}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChangeSelected(e, item.id)}
                />
                <label for="huey">Option 1</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={item.id}
                  name={item.id}
                  value="option2"
                  checked={Selected[item.id] === "option2"}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChangeSelected(e, item.id)}
                />
                <label for="dewey">Option 2</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={item.id}
                  name={item.id}
                  value="option3"
                  checked={Selected[item.id] === "option3"}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChangeSelected(e, item.id)}
                />
                <label for="louie">Option 3</label>
              </div>
              <br />
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Interestingly, "option2" is correctly printed out for me. Maybe try re-visiting the link?

Comment: @Ibz Try to select an option in the list and see the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the useState, the default value is a string, but when you select a radio button you use it as an object.

The reason of your strange console log result is this step:

```
...Selected,
```

You want to desctructure the actual state to keep the previous fields, but as your default state is a string, this string is desctructured, and you desctructure a string, you get an object with one field for each character.

In order to fix it, your state must stay consistent (not a string then an object), you can do it this way:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState({
    1: "option1",
    2: "option3",
    3: "option2"
  });
```

Now, your select state is always an object containing one field for each user.

Edit: if you want to use the same default value for all the users, you can create a function that'll build the default state object.
In this example, you provide the list of users to the function and the default value:

```
function initialSelectedValue(users, defaultValue) {
    var initialState = {};
    for (var i = 1; i <= users.length; i++) {
      initialState[i] = defaultValue;
    }
    return initialState;
  }
```

and you call this function when you declare the useState:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(initialSelectedValue(initialList, "option1"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the whole explanation. I understood what you meant. Now, the problem is, I will be adding elements dynamically to the list, is there a way to set a default value for the new ones ? With your method I think it will be hard.

Comment: You only have to create a function that'll create the default state object, I'll add it to my answer

Comment: Your solution works perfectly thank you very very much. One mor question, why the last element doesn't change at all ? [Check the modified code](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-snowflake-j26b7?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: The initialSelectedValue function was starting the list of item by 0 instead of 1, I'll update it and it'll fix this bug

Comment: It's working ! Thank you very much man really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your initial state is a string and you are using as a object in the `handleChangeSelected`

Just edit it to `const [Selected, setSelected] = useState({});`

Another tips:

- Try not to use capitalized names for variable that isn't a component
- Your list couldn't be a state
- Your id could be the index of the array

Comment: You are right ! const `useState({})` is working. But what if I want to define `option2` as a default value in the selection ? Is there any alternative ?

Comment: You could do something like 

`const [Selected, setSelected] = useState({ 0: "option2", 1: "option2", 2: "option2" });`

Comment: Than you very much. But I'm still close, I want just one default value for every state, is it possible ?

Comment: You could try a function that generates that object for you `getInitialState('option2')`

Comment: Good idea ! Thank you.